# Docker .net framework application

Tags: asp.net, .net, docker, iis, http-status-code-500

I am try to create a working docker image for a legacy .net framework application (.net framework 4.6)
What I did so far:

- I switched my Docker desktop on Windows 10 from Linux containers to Windows
- I deployed the application via right-click "Publish" into a directory
- Create a docker file built and run it

Where I am struggling is executing the application. IIS won't recognize the application and throws a 500 internal server error.

Here my docker file.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis

RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

COPY . .
```

I took the instructions from https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-windows-servercore-iis.

The error I am getting when running the container is the following, when navigating to the page in my browser. `localhost:8000/application/admin`

[image]

To fix the error, I tried the following:

- Tried with image for .net framework 4.8 and 4.6.2
- Changed the `connectionstrings`
- Set `CustomErrors` to `Off`
- Set the permissions to the files in the `wwwroot/inetpub` folder to everyone and full

Unfortunately with I get the same results. It doesn't seems to recognize the application. I struggle even to get the first login page it I don't see anything in the even logs.

I would appreciate any help very much. Thanks in advance!

Edit 1:

- Http error message when calling directly Invoke-WebRequest directly from the container.

[image]

- Fixed .net framework version

Comment: You need to get the error page inside the container so as to learn the detailed error message (or use appcmd/PowerShell to modify IIS setting to show detailed error page remotely), https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/#sample-code

Comment: .net framework 4.8.2  doesn't exist

Comment: *"Here my docker file."* is it your entire dockerfile? it's missing the run command, something like `CMD ["dotnet", "yourproject.dll"]`

Comment: Thanks @LexLi i execute the command but still get the same error from outside. I get a different error when calling it directly from the container. Added the message above.

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski, fixed

Comment: Thanks @RicardoPontual but I am trying to contrainerize a .net framework application < 5

Comment: Do you set url rewrite or reverse proxy code in web.config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for all the help. It pointed me in the right direction. It was necessary to install url re-write and some IIS modules in order for the application to work. Also I experienced issues with the SQL server linux image in Docker desktop mixed mode. But there is an older version of SQL server for windows which worked. https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/mssql-server-windows-developer

Here my docker file I hope it can help somebody else

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore/iis

RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command Remove-Item -Recurse C:\inetpub\wwwroot\*

RUN powershell -Command Invoke-WebRequest http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/D/E/DDE57C26-C62C-4C59-A1BB-31D58B36ADA2/rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi -OutFile c:/inetpub/rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi
RUN powershell -Command Start-Process c:/inetpub/rewrite_amd64_en-US.msi -ArgumentList "/qn" -Wait

RUN cmd /c C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe  unlock config -section:system.webServer/handlers
RUN cmd /c C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe set apppool /apppool.name:DefaultAppPool /enable32BitAppOnWin64:true

RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerRole
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServer
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-CommonHttpFeatures
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpErrors
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpRedirect
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ApplicationDevelopment
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -online -FeatureName NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-NetFxExtensibility45
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpLogging
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-LoggingLibraries
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-RequestMonitor
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpTracing
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-Security
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-RequestFiltering
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-Performance
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebServerManagementTools
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-Metabase
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-StaticContent
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-DefaultDocument
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-WebSockets
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ApplicationInit
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ISAPIExtensions
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ISAPIFilter
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-HttpCompressionStatic
RUN powershell -Command Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-ASPNET45

WORKDIR /inetpub/wwwroot

COPY . .

RUN cmd /c icacls C:/inetpub/wwwroot /grant:r Everyone:F /t
```